# No definition in cpp composition when I define in function

Tags: c++, composition

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Date{

private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

public:
    Date(int dy,int mt,int yr){
        day=dy;
        month=mt;
        year=yr;
    }
    void showDate(){
    cout<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }

};

class Human{
private:
    string name;
    Date birthDay;
public:
    Human(string nm,Date bd):name(nm),birthDay(bd){};

    showHumanInfo(){
        cout<<"The person named : "<<name<<" was born : ";
        birthDay.showDate();
    }

};

int main()
{
    Date birthday(1,2,1995);
    Human h1("alek",birthday);
    h1.showHumanInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

This works, but why it doesn't work when I do the following?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Date{

private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

public:
    Date(int dy,int mt,int yr){
        day=dy;
        month=mt;
        year=yr;
    }
    void showDate(){
    cout<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }

};

class Human{
private:
    string name;
    Date birthDay;
public:
    Human(string nm,Date bd){
        name = nm;
        birthDay = bd;
        }

    showHumanInfo(){
        cout<<"The person named : "<<name<<" was born : ";
        birthDay.showDate();
    }

};

int main()
{
    Date birthday(1,2,1995);
    Human h1("alek",birthday);
    h1.showHumanInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

I have problem like that. Why can't I use date class in a human class?

When I change human public class like that

```
public:
human(){
 //  ...
}
```

It not working it thing is the same think but not adding date class in human class.

Comment: sry i fix just stack number of characters

Comment: I'm surprised that even your first code snippet compiles at all. You are missing a `void` before your `showHumanInfo()` declaration/definition.

Comment: `void showHumanInfo()`. In the second case, when you construct a Human, the birthdate is not initialized. This is what the error is telling you. If you want to allow the birthdate to temporarily not be set, you need a default constructor for it.

Comment: Ignoring the `showHumanInfo()` problem, the second case doesn't compile because `Date` does not have a default constructor.  Use constructor initializer lists:  that's why the first case works.

Comment: @Eljay Is there a compiler command-line option to "ignore the `showHumanInfo()` problem"? ;)

Comment: @AdrianMole • Just wrap all the offending code with `#if IGNORE_THIS_PROBLEM` and `#endif` and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of a constructor, all member variables must be initialized before the body of the constructor is executed. Since `Date` doesn't have a default constructor, there is no way to initialize it

```
Human(string nm, Date bd)
{  // birthDay must be initialized before this point
   // ...
   birthDay = bd; // this is assignment, which is too late
}
```

The fix is to either give `Date` a default constructor, if that makes sense, or to initialize `birthDay` in a member initializer list, as you did in the first example code.

Answer (score 0):

I think problems comes from "birthday = bd;"

It has been a while since the last time I coded in C++ but if I am not wrong, using constructor initialiser and using equal operator are not the same.

You should override "=" operator to use it with your object.

[About his](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)